# Birth-Death Process associated with Orthogonal Polynomials

Tags: pr.probability, fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, mp.mathematical-physics, continued-fractions

I have read in various places the following objects are related:

- orthogonal polynomials
- birth-death processes
- Lattice paths
- continued fractions

After a lot of searching online, I found sketches about the various relationships

- the moments of orthogonal polynomials count weighted lattice paths
- the Kolmogoroff forward/backward equations of birth-death process can be solved using orthogonal polynomials of a given weight.

However the papers have been hard to decipher, such as this one by [Karlin and McGregor](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1957-085-02/S0002-9947-1957-0091566-1/S0002-9947-1957-0091566-1.pdf), or the first few pages in this paper by [Fabrice Gullemin](http://perso.rd.francetelecom.fr/guillemin/PDFfiles/fcont.pdf).

---

The birth-death process on

$$ 1 \rightleftharpoons 2 \rightleftharpoons 3 \rightleftharpoons 4 \rightleftharpoons \dots $$

where $\mathrm{Rate}(n \to n+1)=\lambda_n, \mathrm{Rate}(n+1 \to n)=\mu_n, \mathrm{Rate}(n \circlearrowleft)=-(\mu_n + \lambda_n)$

The Karlin and McGregor showed you can find orthogonal polynomials $Q_n(x)$ with respect to a measure $\mu(dx)$ that solve the transition probabilities (the odds of starting at **m** and winding up at **n** at time **t**)

$$ \mathbb{P}(\Lambda(t) = n | \Lambda(0) = m) = \pi_n \int_0^\infty e^{-tx} Q_n(x)Q_m(x) \mu(dx)$$

They even figured out a way to construct the polynomials

$$ Q_{-1}(x)=0, Q_0(x)=1, \lambda_n Q_{n+1}(x) +(x - \lambda_n - \mu_n) Q_n(x) + \mu_n Q_{n-1}(x) = 0 $$

And then one notices the 3-term relation is the ["magic box" recurrence formula for continued fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_recurrence_formulas).

---

I first read about these relationships in regards to the [Rogers-Ramanujan continued fraction](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~ono/reu09FengKirschMcCallWage.pdf).

\[  r(q)  = \cfrac{1}{1 + \cfrac{q}{1 + \cfrac{q^2}{1 + \dots}}} \quad\quad\quad\quad = 1 - q + q^2 - q^4 + \dots \]

However the birth and death process is rather complicated.

---

**What is the birth-death process associated to the Hermite polynomials or the Legendre polynomials?**

or maybe in general

**What do we reconstruct the birth-death processes correspond to the classical orthogonal polynomials?**

Comment: http://books.google.com/books/about/Stochastic_Processes_and_Orthogonal_Poly.html?id=V2BS_Dmp0XoC

Comment: I don't understand the question. You already seem to have everything you need to determine the answer: given a family of orthogonal polynomials, you find the coefficients of their 3-term recurrence relations, and that tells you the rate constants of the birth-death process.

Comment: Some links in the post seem to be dead, here are Wayback Machine links: [reu09FengKirschMcCallWage.pdf](http://web.archive.org/web/20130903083903/http://www.math.wisc.edu/~ono/reu09FengKirschMcCallWage.pdf) and [fcont.pdf](http://web.archive.org/web/20081015182214/http://perso.rd.francetelecom.fr/guillemin/PDFfiles/fcont.pdf).